# Error decodin signature JWT authentication Android

Tags: android, django, retrofit

I'm using Django with rest_framework and I activated JSONWebTokenAuthentication . Everything seems to work fine when I do a Post for login a user I get a token. If I validate that token in [jwt.io](http://jwt.io/) I get signature validated. But when I send any get or post to an endpoint in my server and in header I put "Authorization: JWT " I get the following.

```
06-26 12:20:58.832    5293-7833/com.infortec.angel.montalbanwebser D/RETROFIT﹕ Authorization: JWT {token:<token>}
06-26 12:20:58.842    5293-7833/com.infortec.angel.montalbanwebser D/RETROFIT﹕ ---> END HTTP (no body)

06-26 12:20:59.322    5293-7833/com.infortec.angel.montalbanwebser 

D/RETROFIT﹕ : HTTP/1.0 403 FORBIDDEN
06-26 12:20:59.332    5293-7833/com.infortec.angel.montalbanwebser D/RETROFIT﹕ Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
06-26 12:20:59.332    5293-7833/com.infortec.angel.montalbanwebser D/RETROFIT﹕ Content-Type: application/json
06-26 12:20:59.332    5293-7833/com.infortec.angel.montalbanwebser D/RETROFIT﹕ Date: Fri, 26 Jun 2015 10:19:34 GMT
06-26 12:20:59.332    5293-7833/com.infortec.angel.montalbanwebser D/RETROFIT﹕ Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.3
06-26 12:20:59.332    5293-7833/com.infortec.angel.montalbanwebser D/RETROFIT﹕ Vary: Accept, Cookie
06-26 12:20:59.332    5293-7833/com.infortec.angel.montalbanwebser D/RETROFIT﹕ X-Android-Received-Millis: 1435314059321
06-26 12:20:59.332    5293-7833/com.infortec.angel.montalbanwebser D/RETROFIT﹕ X-Android-Response-Source: NETWORK 403
06-26 12:20:59.332    5293-7833/com.infortec.angel.montalbanwebser D/RETROFIT﹕ X-Android-Selected-Transport: http/1.1
06-26 12:20:59.332    5293-7833/com.infortec.angel.montalbanwebser D/RETROFIT﹕ X-Android-Sent-Millis: 1435314059296
06-26 12:20:59.332    5293-7833/com.infortec.angel.montalbanwebser D/RETROFIT﹕ X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
06-26 12:20:59.342    5293-7833/com.infortec.angel.montalbanwebser D/RETROFIT﹕ {"detail":"Error decoding signature."}
06-26 12:20:59.342    5293-7833/com.infortec.angel.montalbanwebser D/RETROFIT﹕ <--- END HTTP (38-byte body)
```

> {"detail":"Error decoding signature."}

EDIT: I'm using a RequestInterceptor to add my header.

```
 public class TokenRequestInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor{

    @Override
    public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
        request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.addHeader("Authorization", "JWT " + Utils.token);
    }
}
```

Utils.token is an static field where I store the token when I retrieve it from the server after the authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`D/RETROFIT﹕ Authorization: JWT {token:<token>}`

I think your problem is that you're sending the token as a json object instead of sending the token itself:

`D/RETROFIT﹕ Authorization: JWT <token>`

If you like to send the token as a json you should send it in the body instead than in the Authorization header.

`$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"token":"<TOKEN>"}' URL`